# clojure: No implementation of method of protocol found for class

Tags: clojure

I have a ring server. I am using Buddy for authentication / authorization. I implemented my own token backend by implementing `-parse`, `-authenticate`, and `-handle-unauthorized` of the buddy protocols `IAuthentication` and `IAuthorization`. Here it is:

```clj
(ns myproject.auth
  (:require [buddy.auth.protocols :as proto]))

...

(defn my-token-backend
  ([] (my-token-backend nil))
  ([{:keys [unauthorized-handler]}]
   (reify
     proto/IAuthentication
     (-parse [_ request]
       (token-or-nil))
     (-authenticate [_ request token]
       (get-user-from-token token))
     proto/IAuthorization
     (-handle-unauthorized [_ request metadata]
       (if unauthorized-handler
         (unauthorized-handler request metadata)
         (handle-unauthorized-default request))))))
```

I then use my backend in `wrap-authentication` and `wrap-authorization` middleware:

```clj
(defn middleware [handler]
  (-> handler
      (wrap-authentication my-token-backend)
      (wrap-authorization my-token-backend)
```

...and call my app with that middleware like so:
`(def app (middleware main-routes))`.

When I go to my index page in my browser, I get the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :-parse of protocol: #'buddy.auth.protocols/IAuthentication found for class: myproject.auth$my_token_backend`.

When I call `(reflect my-token-backend)` in the REPL, I noticed the dashes in the names of the methods `-parse`, `-authenticate`, and `-handle-unauthorized` have been converted to underscores. Is this why I'm getting that error, or is the error coming from somewhere else?

---

Edit: After Sean's comment, I've changed my middleware to look like the following:

```clj
(defn middleware [handler]
  (-> handler
      (wrap-authentication (my-token-backend))
      (wrap-authorization (my-token-backend))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `myproject.auth$my_token_backend` is the function `my-token-backend` and the error you are getting says that the call to `-parse` is expecting an object that implements the protocols -- which would be the *result* of *calling* your function.

So I think you want:

```
(defn middleware [handler]
  (-> handler
      (wrap-authentication (my-token-backend))
      (wrap-authorization (my-token-backend)))
```

Comment: Even after changing my code to this, I still get the same error.

Comment: After a few more server restarts, this code seems to have eliminated the error. Thanks.